# How to search any order of a phrase and any word of it from text in C#

Tags: c#, string, search, phrase

I'm try to make searches from a list of products based on the product name and description. I can make it with below search parameter, in which "search" represents the string to be looked for.

```
{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || product.Name.ToLower().Contains(search)) ||
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || product.Description.ToLower().Contains(search))}
```

This does work, for instance, a phrase search like "purus lectus malesuada" whether the phrase appears in the product Name or product Description.
Now I wanted to get the products that contains e.g., "purus" or "purus lectus" or "malesuada purus", i.e., based on any word of the phrase in any order. How the parameter should be modified in Contains method or any other method should be used for more efficient search?

Comment: Just searching for "purus" yields exactly the same result as searching for ("purus" or "purus lectus" or "malesuada purus") because the first condition always matches when one of the others matches.

Comment: Can you show input and expected output?

Comment: `Products.Where(x=> x.Name.ToLower().Contains(search) || Description.ToLower().Contains(search)).ToList();`  This will return a list of products where name or description contains the word you specified in `search` variable

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be to split the search string into distinct words and check if the productname/description contains any of the search words separately.

```
        string search = "purus lectus malesuada";
        var searchWords = search.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var productNames = new[]
        {
            "purus lectus",
            "lorem ipsum",
            "purus lectus malesuada"
        };
        var matches  = productNames.Where(name => searchWords.Any(name.Contains));
```

I hope extending the example to work with your product model & description would not be a major problem. It could also be extended to order the results according to how many of the words where matched.

Another approach might be to check for the [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) between the product name/description and search string. For this to work you probably need to set some minimum length of the longest common substring, or just order the matches according to the length.

A note about the `.ToLower()`, this will create a new string each time it is called, and this will cause allocations. That is typically a bad thing for something like searching that might process millions of items. One workaround is to use `myString.IndexOf(searchString, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0`, this however is for some reason noticable slower than `.Contains()` when I did some measurements. Another workaround might be to run `.ToLower()` once, and store the lowered string between searches. You might even concatenate the product name and description if you do it this way.

Comment: `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is probably faster. If you don't have culture specific casing issues (e.g., Turkish characters) this will work fine.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes I cannot measure any significant difference between InvariantCultureIgnoreCase and OrdinalIgnoreCase.